Godot 4: Button size property not working as it should be
I have a problem with the back button of a menu in my game. The size of the button in the inspector is x: 72px y: 40px.
When I measure the buttons actual size with the ruler, its size is x: 50px y: 27px.
The button is a child of a canvas layer.


I already found help at the godot forum. The problem was that the scale property of the canvas layer the button was part of was 0.7 instead of 1.
